# Can't create Dialog Box inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am not able to create Dialog box inside AsyncTask. Can someone help here? I am getting error "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application".

Here is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    AsyncTaskTest at=new AsyncTaskTest();
                    at.execute();
            }   

            public class AsyncTaskTest extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... vd){
                            try{
                                    String desc = "Show Dialog without error";
                                    publishProgress(desc);
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                    publishProgress("Error: "+e.toString());
                            }
                            return null;
                    }
                    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... msg) {
                            showDialog(msg[0]);
                    }
                    private void showDialog(String msg){
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
                    alertBox.setMessage(msg);
                    alertBox.setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                            }).show();
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You can do UI work in `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`

Comment: I have found the issue here AReader.. The problem is with getApplicationContext(). I used "ma" instead. And already defined global MainActivity ma; and assigned it "this" inside onCreate(). It worked !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing

```
getApplicationContext()
```

to :

```
MainActivity.this
```

for:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
                    alertBox.setMessage(msg);
                    alertBox.setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                            }).show();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use The following instead

```
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        YourActivity.this,
                                android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`

Handler handler=new Handler();

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    AsyncTaskTest at=new AsyncTaskTest();
                    at.execute();
            }   

            public class AsyncTaskTest extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... vd){
                            try{
                                    String desc = "Show Dialog without error";
                                    publishProgress(desc);
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                    publishProgress("Error: "+e.toString());
                            }
                            return null;
                    }
                    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... msg) {
                          handler.postRunnable(new Runnable(){
                            showDialog(msg[0]);
                       });
                    }
                    private void showDialog(String msg){
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
                    alertBox.setMessage(msg);
                    alertBox.setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                    }

                        }).show();
                    }
            }
    }`
```